# nodejs nginx 504 gateway timeout reverese proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to run a NodeJS application on port 2000 of an ubuntu server.

the application runs using pm2.

As far as I can tell the application is running fine as i can use the command:

```
curl http://localhost:2000
```

And I get the web page back almost instantly.

The problem I have is that I am trying to use nginx as the reverse proxy and for SSL. From an SSL perspective this works great as trying to browse to the website 'http://dreamingoftech.uk' I get redirected to the HTTPS version and I get the green padlock. Happy days.

However unfortunately I don't get the webpage but a 504 error.

The strange thing is, if I run:

```
time -p GET -H 'Host: dreamingoftech.uk' http://127.0.0.1:2000
```

I do eventually get the webpage returned (although i have to admit that I don't really know what this command is doing)

I am using the basic nginx.conf file except with these values added:

```
proxy_connect_timeout       600;
proxy_send_timeout          600;
proxy_read_timeout          600;
send_timeout                600;
```

and my sites-available/default file is as follows:

```
#HTTP
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
# HTTPS — proxy all requests to the Node app
server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name dreamingoftech.uk;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dreamingoftech.uk/fullchain.pe$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dreamingoftech.uk/privkey.$

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {

proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2000;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
}
```

In the access logs I get this error, although I am not sure if this is a red herring:

```
 "GET / HTTP/2.0" 504 665 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"
```

My question really is could anyone advise me on the correct setup to get my website to load in a timely manner. I can't understand why a higher timeout is needed if the server is capable of delivering the page almost instantly (although again this could be my naivity).

Thanks in advance

Steve

Comment: `localhost` vs `127.0.0.1` issue? Odd I know but it is a starting point

Comment: @ShawnC. Hi thanks, I tried modifying this in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default however this lead to the same effect.

Comment: I'm going to close this down as the error I am getting now is a 502 error and I don't know haw I got from this to that.